# failed processing Manifest - Xamarin Android

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android, visual-studio-2019

I am building a Xamarin application. I was able to build and deploy my application to the emulator. When I switched to Release to build the apk file. I have started to get these errors related to the manifest `failed processing Manifest`. I do not know what the issue is. all the files required are in presence, but still same error. Yesterday, when I switched back to debug, the errors were gone. but today, both Debug and Release show the same errors. anyone has encounted the same issue. thank you

[image]

Comment: There might be several issues, and I wont be able to tell all the answers since you haven't provided the information needed. First issue I see is that the app is looking for an "icon" file in the drawable folder that was there before, but isnt now. I would suggest opening you project folder inside a code editor like Visual Studio Code and search for all instances of "drawable/icon". If you need that code, you need to add back that icon, or else delete that code. If there's no instances, then you probably just need to delete the bin & obj folders containing temporary files

Comment: And then share the code inside your device_filter.xml and of your AndroidManifest files since there seems to be errors inside them. Open the manifest file in VS Code if you don't know how to get the source code.

Answer (score 0):

Have a check with the properties of file : **Build Action** whether is **AndroidResource**

[image]